# Detecting All Changes to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I am looking to create a program that will compare two dataframes and detect the changes made to each dataframe. This is for a version control application in which an original file has been manipulated by a user and I am attempting to extract the changes they made to the original file.

Attempted naive solution:

```
import pandas as pd 


# Initalize the data
data_original = [['4', 'NYC','New York'], ['3', 'BOS','Boston'], ['2', 'CHI','Chicago']]
data_new = [['4', 'NYC','New York','50'], ['3', 'Boston','Boston','100'], ['2', 'CHI','Chicago','20'], ['8', 'LA','Los Angeles','30']] 

# Create the dataframes
df_original = pd.DataFrame(data_original, columns = ['Office Number', 'Office Name','Office Location'])
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_new, columns = ['Office Number', 'Office Name','Office Location','Money'])

df_changes = df_new[ ~df_new.isin(df_original)].dropna()
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
['8', 'LA','Los Angeles','30']
```

This naive solution is not what I am looking for because it does not detect the change of "BOS" to "Boston" in the second item of the dataframe. I am looking for something that would indicate even if a single item in a row has been changed. The addition or subtraction of columns I can figure out separately, but how can element-wise changes such as "BOSTON" to "Boston" be detected?

Comment: You could do an anti join on all columns...not sure if that will take too much time if your dataframe is too big.

Comment: If additional rows can only ever be added to the end and you need to compare across the index (i.e. row 1 in df_original is always compared to row 1 in df_new) then this is very simple. However, if rows can appear in any order then and you still need to make such a comparison this is a very very very complicated problem.

Comment: @JasonChia Anti-join was an originally attempted solution, took too long and encountered problems on limited RAM device. Thank you for the suggestion.

at ALollz: Data is not always indexed and edits can be made within the database in any order. This is one of the complexities of the problem.

All, please see accepted solution which is excellent. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Comprehensive Check

```
def compare(old, new):
    new_cols = new.columns.difference(old.columns)
    del_cols = old.columns.difference(new.columns)
    new_indx = new.index.difference(old.index)
    del_indx = old.index.difference(new.index)

    # Now that we've checked new and deleted rows and columns
    # `align` the dataframes and check the values
    old, new = old.align(new, 'inner')

    I, J = np.where(old.ne(new))
    c = old.columns
    r = old.index

    changes = pd.DataFrame([
        [r[i], c[j], old.iat[i, j], new.iat[i, j]]
        for i, j in zip(I, J)
    ], columns=['Row', 'Column', 'Old', 'New'])

    return changes, new_cols, del_cols, new_indx, del_indx
```

---

#### Demonstration

Get change data

```
changes, new_cols, del_cols, new_indx, del_indx = compare(df_original, df_new)
```

Print a nice report

```
print(f"""\
New Columns:
{' '.join(new_cols.astype(str))}

Deleted Columns:
{' '.join(del_cols.astype(str))}

New Rows:
{' '.join(new_indx.astype(str))}

Deleted Rows:
{' '.join(del_indx.astype(str))}

Changes:
{changes}
""")

New Columns:
Money

Deleted Columns:


New Rows:
3

Deleted Rows:


Changes:
   Row       Column  Old     New
0    1  Office Name  BOS  Boston
```

## _______________________________________________________

## Simpler Solution

We can forgo the breakdown of finding added and deleted columns and rows and just interpret null values in the `changes` dataframe appropriately.

```
def compare(old, new):
    old, new = old.align(new)  # Notice I don't use `'inner'` as I did before

    I, J = np.where(old.ne(new))
    c = old.columns
    r = old.index

    changes = pd.DataFrame([
        [r[i], c[j], old.iat[i, j], new.iat[i, j]]
        for i, j in zip(I, J)
    ], columns=['Row', 'Column', 'Old', 'New'])

    return changes

compare(df_original, df_new)

   Row           Column  Old          New
0    0            Money  NaN           50
1    1            Money  NaN          100
2    1      Office Name  BOS       Boston
3    2            Money  NaN           20
4    3            Money  NaN           30
5    3  Office Location  NaN  Los Angeles
6    3      Office Name  NaN           LA
7    3    Office Number  NaN            8
```

In this case, the only change is represented by the non-null value in the `'Old'` column.  All others are new.

## _______________________________________________________

## Safer Solution

In the case that you have `np.nan` in both the new and old dataframes, this will evaluate to be not equal.  This version, accounts for that.

However, it still won't catch if one dataframe had `None` and the other had `np.nan`.  I'll leave that as an exercise for future readers.

```
def compare(old, new):
    old, new = old.align(new)

    I, J = np.where(old.ne(new))
    c = old.columns
    r = old.index

    data = []
    for i, j in zip(I, J):
        n = new.iat[i, j]
        o = old.iat[i, j]
        if pd.notna(n) or pd.notna(o):
            data.append([r[i], c[j], o, n])

    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Row', 'Column', 'Old', 'New'])
```

Comment: This is the best solution to the problem as stated. Solves the item based change as well as the column changes which were not even the main topic of the question. Excellent solution.

Comment: I've updated the post with more information that you may find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need?

```
df_changes = df_new[ ~df_new[["Office Number","Office Name","Office Location"]].apply(tuple,1).isin(df_original[["Office Number","Office Name","Office Location"]].apply(tuple,1))].dropna()
```

Don't know if the dropna() is still needed now. You can set the columns as a tuple so its immutable and you are comparing across keys. Tested with your test data and it works I think.

Answer (score 1):

**If the comparison is along the indices** then we need two `reindexlike` calls. The first allows for a comparison of the original with the new DataFrame, regardless of additional rows or columns. The second marks all additional rows and columns as `True`. The resulting DataFrame is `True` where `df_new` differs from `df_original`.

```
m = (df_new.reindex_like(df_original)
           .ne(df_original)
           .reindex_like(df_new)
           .fillna(True))

   Office Number  Office Name  Office Location  Money
0          False        False            False   True
1          False         True            False   True
2          False        False            False   True
3           True         True             True   True

# Can slice to see changes
df_new[m]
  Office Number Office Name Office Location Money
0           NaN         NaN             NaN    50
1           NaN      Boston             NaN   100
2           NaN         NaN             NaN    20
3             8          LA     Los Angeles    30
```